# Error when using if-else shorthand operator at var declaration

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I was typing out this part of my script:

```
var newLat = /* value for newLat */ ;
...
var newLatDir = ((newLat >== 0) ? "N" : "S");
```

However, the Eclipse IDE gave the following error at the `newLatDir` declaration, and on testing my webpage no longer works:

```
Expected an identifier and instead saw '='
```

What's going on here, and why?

Comment: Note that none of the `()` in `var newLatDir = ((newLat >== 0) ? "N" : "S");` serve any purpose.

Comment: And FWIW, the "if-else shorthand operator" is called the *conditional* operator (sometimes called "the ternary operator," although that's slightly incorrect; it's **a** ternary operator [an operator accepting three operands], but someday JavaScript could get another ternary operator).

Comment: @t-j-crowder I know the brackets don't do anything, it's my practice to put them to make identifying precedence easier and more readable, especially in more complex statements.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `>==` operator in JavaScript; use `>=` instead:

```
var newLatDir = ((newLat >= 0) ? "N" : "S");
```

Comment: What's the reason that there's no >== operator? Given how there's versions of almost every operator that has an additional equal sign such as ===, !== etc.